# Can we get an off-topic link to law.stackexchange.com

Tags: feature-request

Many questions here belong there but there is no way as yet for flagging them for migration.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we migrate questions to other SE sites?](http://meta.workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/2112/how-can-we-migrate-questions-to-other-se-sites)

Comment: @MaskedMan this doesn't look like a duplicate.  That question asks how to migrate to sites that aren't options; this question asks for a new option.  (Also, and I don't know how significant this is, that question was asked when we were still in beta, when it's *very* unusual to have other options.  Graduated sites can ask for custom migrations, though you still have to make a case.)

Comment: Dale, in order to consider adding a custom migration target, the team will need to see a convincing argument backed by data.  Which questions *that are not poor questions anywhere* ("don't migrate crap") should have been migrated to Law?  A list of such questions that the community agrees on would help.  Thanks.

Comment: @MonicaCellio While that may be true, Jim's answer to that question adequately answers this question, in particular, the point about this being intentional, and the link which points to an answer on meta.SE by Jeff Atwood. (A few years ago, I learned on SO that when flagging a question as duplicate, the answers have to be considered as well.)

Answer (score 6):

Law.SE is a beta site, and as such [isn't available as a target for migration](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178444/should-beta-sites-be-listed-for-migration-suggestions).  Moderators can migrate, of course, but it can't be a target in the Off Topic close reasons until/unless Law graduates.

It's quite unclear how close Law would be to graduating, even if they do approve the new half-graduation (where they graduate 'ready' sites without waiting for a design, which would include permitting them to be a migration target); they've not even been in beta 90 days, and most graduated sites are in beta for *years*.  Their statistics aren't bad, but they're not stellar enough to suggest they'd graduate substantially ahead of the norm.

What that does mean, though, is you can begin compiling statistics now as to how many questions would be migrate-worthy (ie, how many you'd vote to migrate if it were in the offtopic list), and how many migrated (by moderators) questions are both a) approved by the Law.SE community (ie, not rejected) and b) become good Law questions (ie, get upvotes and good answers).  That way, when Law does graduate, you've got the statistics ready to make the argument.

Comment: Moderators and 10k users should have access to closed question stats,which includes a list of the custom off-topic comments; this should be useful in determining what kind of migration volume you'd have.